# App crashes at startup

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, location, google-play-services

My app crashes at startup when changing to use the services Google Play Location Services. Is it because I am compiling version 8.4.0 ? I tried using 8.3.0 version of the services, but I had no success.

```
01-30 17:58:48.394 7665-7665/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.example.eskimo, PID: 7665
                                             java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzz(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzx; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx' appears in /data/data/com.example.eskimo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-base-10.0.1_a42d2fa8b24ba1e57daa64ccb04411c53a7591a5-classes.dex)
                                                 at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.zzaT(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                 at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1789)
                                                 at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1764)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6767)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6362)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6302)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:222)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1861)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here is my build.gradle file

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.eskimo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        jackOptions {
            enabled false
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {

    }

    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:17.0'
    compile files('libs/mobileservices-2.0.1-beta-javadoc.jar')
    compile files('libs/mobileservices-2.0.1-beta-sources.jar')
    compile files('libs/mobileservices-2.0.1-beta.jar')
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:2.0.3'
    compile project(':MPChartLib3')
    compile project(':ButtonsLib')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'

}
```

Comment: The error quotes "instant run", did you try to *stop* the app on the emulator, and start it back from Android Studio to bypass instant run?

Answer (score 3):

In your gradle file, the play-services-maps entry is duplicated, 8.4 and 10.0.1 on the last line. I would delete the second one if you want to use 8.4.

Android 2.3 and above devices should automatically update play services so you would be ok deleting the reference to 8.4 and using 10.0.1 so it is more up-to-date.

Comment: I did not notice that !

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

Before

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
```

After

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
```